# Adding custom permission for specific device cause any issues in android playstore?

Tags: android, android-permissions, honeywell

I recently added hardware barcode scan support to our app for honey well devices. As per the document I have added this permission in android manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.honeywell.decode.permission.DECODE" />
```

And reading data using data intent-broadcast receiver mechanism.

Is this cause any issues in play store release of existing app. How this type of custom permission work for specific devices?